# shutterstock: API for uploading images

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-upload, shutterstock

How to upload images to shutterstock using javascript/NodeJs. I have gone through the following API but couldn't find the particular API.

> https://github.com/silas/node-shutterstock#v1.customer.images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutterstock doesn't currently have a public API for submitting images.